# Set a footer template on Angular UI grid when group feature is enabled

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Can you tell me how to set a footer template on [**Angular UI grid**](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/209_grouping) when group feature is enabled ?

Here is the [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/U1g66VRbr338J8JZCfmE).

I have tried like this.But it's not working.I need to set a `Total Properties` on the `Balance` column.

```
footerCellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">Total Properties 
{{customTreeAggregationFinalizerFn: function (aggregation) { 
aggregation.rendered = aggregation.value; }}} </div>', treeAggregationType: 
uiGridGroupingConstants.aggregation.COUNT
```

**Update :**

This is working when for simple aggregation where without Groping.But how can I use it with the Grouping ?

```
{ field: 'balance',  footerCellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-
contents">Total Properties {{col.getAggregationValue() | number:2 }}</div>', 
aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.count}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just set aggregationLabel property on the column to add the "Total Properties"

```
  { name: 'balance', width: '45%', cellFilter: 'currency', treeAggregationType: uiGridGroupingConstants.aggregation.AVG, customTreeAggregationFinalizerFn: function( aggregation ) {
        aggregation.rendered = aggregation.value;
      },aggregationLabel : "Total Properties : " }
```